# Pandas Timestamp vs. Series depending on index used?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, types, timestamp

Can somebody explain why this happens:

```
In [286]: type(df.date.ix[0])
Out[286]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

In [287]: type(df.date.ix[[0]])
Out[287]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

and

```
In [285]: df.date.ix[[0]]
Out[285]: 0   2015-11-03 14:57:27
          Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [283]: df.date.ix[0]
Out[283]: Timestamp('2015-11-03 14:57:27')
```

I want to pull that specific element from my Pandas DataFrame as a `datetime64[ns]` type object. But it all depends on where my index is an `ndarray` or just an `integer`. If it's an `ndarray`, it returns a `datetime64` object and if its an `integer` it returns a `Timestamp` object.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a list or array to `Series.ix`, pandas is assuming you want to slice out a subset of the series so it returns a series, even if it's just one element. If you pass in a scalar, it will assume you want just the value at that index.

You can see more examples at [label based](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/indexing.html#selection-by-label) and [positional based](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/indexing.html#indexing-integer) indexing in the docs.

To your second question, what happens if the `ndarray` has more than one element?

Comment: Ah, makes sense. If the ndarray has more than one element: `In [76]: df.date[[0,1,2]]
Out[76]: 
0   2015-11-03 14:57:27
1   2015-11-03 14:52:13
2   2015-11-03 14:47:11
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
`